# How can I underline a text on ELL?

Tags: support, formatting

How can I underline a text on ELL? I'm trying to underline some words in a question on ELL but I fail to manage it. My browser is Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Quoting myself](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15348/191178):

> Underlining is used to designate links. That's all. If you need *something*, you can use the wealth of options that are supported in posts such as **bold**, *italics*, headers, block quotes, or even just regular "quoting". (Many of these can be combined too.)

To expand on this:

- **Bold** or *italics* are your options for adding emphasis. This is probably what you're looking for; where traditional typography uses underlines, the web uses one of these. I usually prefer italics since it's not as in-your-face, but both are an option if you need to highlight a word or phrase.
- Headers are used to create sections within your post. You really only need these if you're writing something so long that it's hard to skip through.
- Blockquotes are for example sentences or when you use a sentence or more of someone else's words (or, if you're like me, your own words from elsewhere).
- Use "quotes" if you're using less than a sentence of someone else's words and it's part of a sentence that you wrote. Quotes are also good when mentioning phrases.

Other than "quotes" (which are characters that should be on your keyboard), all of these formatting options can be added from the toolbar. In comments, your options are bold or italics, which are created with asterisks around words: `**bold** or *italics*`. (And that formatting I used there is for code. Since this isn't a programming site, it's almost never appropriate and causes its own issues. Don't use it!)